# Replace upper case word in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to replace words that are in all caps with a translated counterpart.

For example, I would like to replace the written number "ONE" with "UNO".

However, when "one" appears in the foreign language in various words it is replaced by "uno".
I only need to replace the capitalized word.

```vb
'ONE
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "ONE"
    .Replacement.Text = "UNO"
    .Forward = False
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

A better option might be to replace when it shows up as the whole word.

Edit: You just set `.MatchWholeWord` to true.

Comment: Make MatchCase = True & MatchWholeWord = True

Comment: @BigBen, be nice please..

Comment: @Aldert, how was editing the question with the ms-word tag not nice? I'm missing something. Oh, do you think I added the last sentence? Not me, that was OP, as is evident in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73830664/revisions).

Comment: @BigBen, maybe I misunderstood your edit, It seemed the duh came from you. My apology, you are nice :-)

Comment: @OP, be nice please..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! :D I added that before any responses as I had found the solution and felt like a dummy. 

For some reason now I'm having the problem where it's replacing all instances of "One" despite me having MatchWholeWord on :/

Answer (score 1):

To do this in bulk you might use code like:

```
Sub MultiFindReplace()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim FList As String, RList As String, i As Long
FList = "ZERO|ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN|EIGHT|NINE|TEN|ELEVEN|TWELVE"
RList = "CERO|UNO|DOS|TRES|CUATRO|CINCO|SEIS|SIETE|OCHO|NUEVE|DIEZ|ONCE|DOCE"
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Format = False
  .Forward = True
  .MatchCase = True
  .MatchWholeWord = True
   'Process each item from the Find/Replace Lists
  For i = 0 To UBound(Split(FList, "|"))
    .Text = Split(FList, "|")(i)
    .Replacement.Text = Split(RList, "|")(i)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This code looks much nicer than what I'm using. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work :/ admittedly a novice to VBA, but when I'm running it nothing is changing. Did you test it? Problem might be on my end. Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: There was a typo in the code. Try it now.

Comment: Hey again, Macropod. I just realized that it is replacing all text in the document (amazing, so much quicker than my code) but it is not replacing the text in the actual header. I have tried troubleshooting this for a few hours, but no clue why it's replacing the text in the doc but not the header. Do you know what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

just set .MatchWholeWord to true!

Answer (score 0):

To process content in headers, footers, endnotes, footnotes, etc., as well as the document body, you would use code like:

```
Sub MultiFindReplaceEverywhere()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, Sctn As Section, Shp As Shape, HdFt As HeaderFooter, h As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For Each Rng In .StoryRanges
    Call FndRep(Rng)
    For Each Shp In Rng.ShapeRange
      With Shp
        If Not .TextFrame Is Nothing Then
          Call FndRep(.TextFrame.TextRange)
        End If
      End With
    Next
  Next
  For Each Sctn In .Sections
    For Each HdFt In Sctn.Headers
      With HdFt
        If .Exists = True Then
          If .LinkToPrevious = False Then
            Call FndRep(HdFt.Range)
            For Each Shp In HdFt.Shapes
              With Shp
                If Not .TextFrame Is Nothing Then
                  Call FndRep(.TextFrame.TextRange)
                End If
              End With
            Next
          End If
        End If
      End With
    Next
    For Each HdFt In Sctn.Footers
      With HdFt
        If .Exists = True Then
          If .LinkToPrevious = False Then
            Call FndRep(HdFt.Range)
            For Each Shp In HdFt.Shapes
              With Shp
                If Not .TextFrame Is Nothing Then
                  Call FndRep(.TextFrame.TextRange)
                End If
              End With
            Next
          End If
        End If
      End With
    Next
  Next
End With
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = h
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub FndRep(Rng As Range)
Dim FList As String, RList As String, i As Long
FList = "ZERO|ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN|EIGHT|NINE|TEN|ELEVEN|TWELVE"
RList = "CERO|UNO|DOS|TRES|CUATRO|CINCO|SEIS|SIETE|OCHO|NUEVE|DIEZ|ONCE|DOCE"
With Rng.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Format = False
  .Forward = True
  .MatchCase = True
  .MatchWholeWord = True
   'Process each item from the Find/Replace Lists
  For i = 0 To UBound(Split(FList, "|"))
    .Text = Split(FList, "|")(i)
    .Replacement.Text = Split(RList, "|")(i)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
End Sub
```